# How to make column sorting false using Ui Component in magento2?

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent

I want to make sorting false for donloaded column :

```
 <column name="downloaded" class="Tatva\Subscription\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Downloadedrenderer">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Downloaded</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After Magento 2.2 you can make sorting false using below code.

```
<sortable>false</sortable>
```

Complete column tag looks like this

```
 <column name="store_id" class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Purchase Point</label>
            <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
            <sortable>false</sortable>
        </settings>
    </column>
```

Answer (score 16):

Try -

```
<item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
```

This works with default grids

Comment: The other one is more concise with the op question, but this one works great with <column> childDefaults item

Answer (score 0):

If your are using argument use like this

```
<column name="uses">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Uses</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

If you are using the setting

```
 <column name="grand_total" class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Price">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Grand Total (Purchased)</label>
                <sortable>false</sortable>
            </settings>
        </column>
```